# 大容量シートを含むExcelファイルを高速で開く方法

Tags: c#, excel

Googleで検索して答えが出てこなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきます。

C#のアプリケーションでExcelファイルを開き、内容をXMLで出力するアプリケーションを開発しています。
開く対象のExcelファイルは2つのシートで構成されています。
1枚目は100,000行300列ほどある大容量のシート
2枚目は100行20列ほどのシートになります。

2枚目のシートを使いたいのですが、1枚目のシートが大容量であるために開くのに時間がかかります。
試したライブラリは標準のExcel用Interop, EPPlus 4.x, ClosedXMLです。
この中ではEPPlusが一番はやいのですが、それでも90秒程度かかりました。

上記の場合、高速にアクセスする手段は他に考えられますか?

※前提条件として、1book2sheets固定です。複数のbookにすることはできないです。
また、Excelをやめる ということも現状できないこととします。

Comment: シート別に２つのファイルに分けるのが良いと思います。使わない１枚目のjシートを開く必要がなくなりますから。

Comment: @Fumu7 全くそのとおりでございます。ただし、今回はシートを分けることができない & Excelをやめることができない を前提条件とさせてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ライブラリを使って読み込む速度比較としては[ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)が一番早い(※)と思います。

下記のサンプルコードでは
`A1`から`Z65535`まで1-26の整数の入っている`Sheet1`と、
`A1`に`ほげ`と書かれただけの`Sheet2`が存在する
`Book1.xlsx`を読み込んでいます。

Office2016のInterop, EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML, ExcelDataReaderを使用して速度計測を行いました。
EPPlus以降は2020年のクリスマス時点でNugetから取得した最新のライブラリを使用しています。

※ExcelDataReaderには、DataSetとして全シート全セルの情報を取得する方法と`NextResult`でシートを読み飛ばす方法があります。今回は後者の方法を利用しました。

**実行結果**

```
1回目
Interop: 3244 ms.
EPPlus: 4396 ms.
NPOI: 11008 ms.
ClosedXML: 19601 ms.
ExcelDataReader: 1605 ms.

2回目
Interop: 3257 ms.
EPPlus: 4619 ms.
NPOI: 11130 ms.
ClosedXML: 20645 ms.
ExcelDataReader: 1771 ms.
```

**サンプルコード**

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using ExcelDataReader;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"Book1.xlsx";
            var sheetName = "Sheet2";
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            // Microsoft.Office.Interop
            stopwatch.Start();
            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = false;
            var oBook = (app.Workbooks.Open(path));
            var oSheet = oBook.Sheets[sheetName];
            Console.WriteLine(oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Text);
            oBook.Close();
            app.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Interop: {0} ms.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // EPPlus
            stopwatch.Restart();
            var fi = new FileInfo(path);
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
            {
                var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];
                Console.WriteLine(sheet.GetValue(1, 1));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("EPPlus: {0} ms.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // NPOI
            stopwatch.Restart();
            var nBook = WorkbookFactory.Create(path);
            var nSheet = nBook.GetSheet(sheetName);
            Console.WriteLine(nSheet.GetRow(0).Cells[0].StringCellValue);
            nBook.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("NPOI: {0} ms.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // ClosedXML
            stopwatch.Restart();
            using (var book = new XLWorkbook(path))
            {
                var sheet = book.Worksheet(sheetName);
                Console.WriteLine(sheet.Cell(1, 1).Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("ClosedXML: {0} ms.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // ExcelDataReader
            stopwatch.Restart();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                while (reader.Name != sheetName)
                {
                    reader.NextResult();
                }
                reader.Read();
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("ExcelDataReader: {0} ms.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

未検証ですが、Excelファイルを事前に加工するという力業があります。

xlsxファイルの中身は、主にxmlファイルが格納されたzipファイルになっています。
`xl/workbook.xml`にシートの一覧情報があります。

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
...
  <sheets>
    <sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/>
    <sheet name="Sheet2" sheetId="2" r:id="rId2"/>
    <sheet name="Sheet3" sheetId="3" r:id="rId3"/>
  </sheets>
...
</workbook>
```

不要な(大容量の)シートのsheetタグを削除してxlsxファイルに再格納すれば、そのシートが存在しない状態のxlsxファイルになります。
zipファイルとxmlファイルの読み書きなので、.NETであれば豊富にサンプルがあるかと思います。

この方法には制約がありますので、質問者の環境で試して頂くのがいいかと思います。

- シート名は事前にわかっていないといけない。
- 残す方のシートが、削除する方のシートを参照していてはいけない。(数式や名前など)

Answer (score 0):

Interopでも遅い、つまりExcel本体より早く開きたいという要望自体が無茶ではないでしょうか？

[Excel のパフォーマンス: 計算パフォーマンスの強化](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance) など、Excelファイルそのものを改善するか、それでも無理な場合は、Access等のデータベースに移行することを検討されてはどうでしょうか。