# LOOKUP関数を使ったセルからその計算結果の値を取得できない

Tags: c#, excel

ClosedXML(Version: 0.95.4.0)を利用してエクセルのセルからデータを読み込もうとしています。 言語はC#を使っています。ほとんどのセルからはデータ取得ができたのですが、LOOKUP関数を使っているセルの読み込みに失敗します。

エラーです。

```
ClosedXML.Excel.CalcEngine.Exceptions.NameNotRecognizedException: 'The
identifier `LOOKUP` was not recognised.'
```

[この記事](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Evaluating-Formulas)の内容を読みました。ClosedXMLでサポートされていない関数があるようで、`LOOKUP`関数は、サポートされていないようです。

`LOOKUP`関数を使っているセルの値を取得する方法はないのでしょうか？

```
IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell(rowPosi, colPosi);

switch (cell.DataType)
{
    case XLDataType.Number:     
        value = cell.GetFormattedString();
        break;

    case XLDataType.DateTime:   
        DateTime dt = cell.GetDateTime();
        value = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        break;

    case XLDataType.Text:       
        if (cell.CachedValue != null)
        {
            value = cell.CachedValue.ToString();
        }
        else {
            value = cell.Value.ToString();//ここでエラーが発生
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご自身で確認されたWikiおよび`ClosedXML/Lookup.cs`の[ソースコード](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/78150efbbd4a36d65e95ef3c793f12feb12c1a9c/ClosedXML/Excel/CalcEngine/Functions/Lookup.cs)にあるように未対応のようです。
[ClosedXMLで使用できる関数・数式](http://pg.w-news.jp/?eid=16)の記事では2016年にはVLOOKUPが使えなかったようですが現在では実装されているので、今後実装されるかもしれません。

下記の回避策が考えられます。

- EPPlusなど他のライブラリを使用する

  - バージョン 5.7.3でLOOKUPの値を読めることを確認しました。
- try-catchで例外処理をして運用でカバーする

  - 疑似的なLOOKUP関数をC#内で作成し、該当箇所のみ再計算する
  - 該当箇所をVLOOKUPなどに書き換えて運用で回避する
  - 例外部分のみ他のライブラリを併用してカバーする
- (ハードルは高いですが)実装してプルリクエストする

検証用のEPPlusのコードは[別回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/72876)から流用しました。

Comment: EPPlusで実装しようとしましたが、有償だったのでやめました。（https://www.epplussoftware.com/ja/LicenseOverview/）その他の選択肢でExcelDataReaderのパフォーマンスが良さそうだったのですが、日本語が文字化け(http://www.ria-lab.com/archives/1674)するというようなことが書かれていたので使わず、最終的にNPOIで実装し、うまく動作させることができました。